# Action of UITapGestureRecognizer cannot be called while it’s already in progress?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, selector

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` set up which performs a `0.8s` `UIView` animation. What I’m trying to do is allow the user to interrupt during that `0.8s`. I’ll handle the animation side of things (i.e. making the thing animate from its current position), but the current issue is that any further taps during those `0.8s` do not call the `@selector` from the recognizer. Any subsequent taps are blocked until the first run through the `@selector` is finished.

Just to confirm, what I need is a means of allowing the same `@selector` from the same `UITapGestureRecognizer` to be called, even if it didn’t `return` yet. At that point I can override the animation, tell it to begin from its current position, and have it complete even if the user spams the recognizer.

Is there a way to do this? I considered threading, but I’m under the impression I shouldn’t be doing UI updates on background threads so I’m hesitant to try that when there’s likely a preferred way.

Comment: can you post your animation code ?

Comment: It’s just a standard `UIView animateWithDuration` call which sets a transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you want to allow user interaction during animation, add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option, here is example,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     // your animations
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // completion
                 }];
```

Comment: Hmm, that got it. It blocked the entire thread while it was being called. Intriguing.